# How to create smart, nested links?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

in routing

```
     resources :departments do
       resources :buildings do
         resources :halls do
       end
       resources :chairs do
         resources :buildings do
           resources :halls do
         end
       end
     end
```

I want to share the same views of `buildings` and `halls` between `chairs` and `departments`. And I am thinking to create url's in views this way:

`link_to "Show", [@department, @chair, @building, @hall].compact`

If `@chair` doesn't exist, it's gonna be `nil`, so upper link will generate:

`link_to "Show", [@department, @building, @hall]`

If `@chair` exist:

`link_to "Show", [@department, @chair, @building, @hall]`

My question is: How to create this way url's to `edit`, or `new` action? Or maybe there exist better solution for this problem with this kind of nested resources?

Comment: It's not generally advised to nest resources more than one level deep.

Comment: I second Jimmy's comment. Here's a popular post that covers nested resources. I recommend you take a look at it. http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2007/2/5/nesting-resources

Comment: Thank's guys for sugestion and for a link ... maybe i should think to resign of nested resources, and create only one deep level of them, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can stick a symbol in the array as well. So something like this:

```
link_to "Edit", [:edit, @department, @chair, @building, @hall]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an application where we nest three up to four resources deep. One example is the management of contacts. We have Company, Location and Contact models.

Usually you can access the new and edit paths with `new_department_chair_building_path(@department,@chair)`.

Do not forget to include the hidden ID's from your predecessors (deparment, chair) in the form for a new building.

In your building controller you will have to filter out what objects to load depending on the the context. We do it something like this

```
# Company controller
def index
  if params[:project]
    @project = ....
  end
end
```

There may be better ways to do this, but we haven't found any.

In the views we check for `@project` and then render partials.

I hope this may somewhat help you.

Cheers,

Dan